# C# Threads on events in a background-service

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, filesystemwatcher

I'm developing a background service that is processing some recurring tasks. Two of them are:

1. Getting emails from a mail-server every 60 seconds

At the moment I'm using a System.Threading.Timer-instance that fires every 60 seconds. What is best practice here? Is every timercallback executed in a seperate thread? I have seen that System.Timers.Timer could be a better solution. Any experience?

2. Watching folders for incoming files (using FileSystemWatcher)

Same question here: Is every triggered event ( e.g. a file has been inserted) executed in a seperate thread?

The service is also performing some long-running tasks which I may consider executing them in a seperate task. Assuming if not/In case the main thread is performing them - nevertheless are the other events fired?

Comment: Why don't you run some tests? We are here to help solve specific problems you hit, not to design your code nor do your research for you.

Comment: I can run some tests, indeed. And I don't want to do someone else research for me. But maybe someone has knowledge to share?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for System.Timers.Timer at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx is fairly comprehensive; in short yes, there may be multiple threads involved.

Same with FileSystemWatcher - the events are raised on a threadpool thread if I recall correctly.